# TreeView HierarchicalDataTemplate with multiple nested node-types and potentially "infinite" levels

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have three classes viz.

```
public class ConfiguratorObjectViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public string Id { get; set; }
        
        public string ParentId { get; set; }
    
    public ObservableCollection<ConfiguratorAttributeViewModel> Attributes { get; set; } 
        
    public ObservableCollection<ConfiguratorObjectFamilyViewModel> Children { get; set; }   
}
```

```
public class ConfiguratorObjectFamilyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public string Id { get; set; }
        
        public string ParentId { get; set; }
        
    public ObservableCollection<ConfiguratorObjectViewModel> ConfiguratorObjects { get; set; }  
}
```

```
public class ConfiguratorAttributeViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public string Id { get; set; }
        
    public string ParentId { get; set; }    
}
```

I wish to get a TreeView HierarchicalDataTemplate that recursively builds a tree of potentially infinite depth, depending on the data available, for example

```
-Root(ConfiguratorObject)
    |-Family1(ConfiguratorObjectFamily)
        |-Object1(ConfiguratorObject)
        |-Object2(ConfiguratorObject)
            |-AnotherFamily(ConfiguratorObjectFamily)
                |-AnotherObject1(ConfiguratorObject)
                |-AnotherObject2(ConfiguratorObject)
    |-Family2(ConfiguratorObjectFamily)
    |-Famil3(ConfiguratorObjectFamily)
```

I tried this, which works, but is limited because some values(levels) will not show ...

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding RootObject}" >
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
             <!--Root--> 
            <local:ConfiguratorObjectTreeItem  />
            
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate  ItemsSource="{Binding ConfiguratorObjects}">
                     <!--Children--> 
                    <local:ConfiguratorObjectTreeItem  />
                    
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                             <!--Variants--> 
                            <local:ConfiguratorObjectTreeItem  />                                        

                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

</TreeView>
```

I tried the solution provided above. The solution "works" but is static -  is limited on the number of levels that are shown on the tree. I need a solution that is dynamic. Any help will be appreciated!

## Edit

I have tried @BionicOCode suggestion but get only the root node

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding RootObject}" >
    <TreeView.Resources>
    
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ConfiguratorObjectFamilyViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <local:ConfiguratorObjectTreeItem  />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    
     <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ConfiguratorObjectViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding ConfiguratorObjects}" >
            <local:ConfiguratorObjectTreeItem  />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>   

    </TreeView.Resources>

</TreeView>
```

Comment: The solution is to define the  templates as implicit DataTemplate: define a HiearchicalDataTemplate for each data model type (you *must* set the DataType property) that is allowed to have children. Only define the top level of every particular node type (don't set the HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate property). Then add each template to a ResourceDictionary within the scope of the TreeView (e.g. TreeView.Resources or App.xaml etc). This way, for each occurring data model in the tree the matching template will be implicitly applied (recursively).

Comment: Don't forget to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on *every* binding source that does not extend DependencyObject (for example ConfiguratorAttributeViewModel). DependencyObjects must implement their properties that serve as a binding source as dependency properties.

Comment: @BionicCode. I tried your solution, but get only the root node ...

Comment: The INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented in a base class inherited by the ViewModels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  must define all templates as implicit `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. This means you *must* set the `HierarchicalDataTemplate.DataType` property and add the template without an explicit key to a `ResourceDictionary` within the scope of the `TreeView` (for example `TreeView.Resources` or *App.xaml*).
Now, when you define an implicit `HierarchicalDataTemplate` (or `DataTemplate` if the node can't have or is not allowed to have children) for each data model type, WPF will automatically load the matching template for the current data model type in the tree.

Alternatively define a `DataTemplateSelector` to explicitly select the template to load for the current data model.

The following example shows how to define the data tree visual appearance implicitly to allow fully dynamic tree structure with dynamic tree levels (depth and width/breadth) and tree compositions. The tree randomly contains orange, yellow and blue nodes that are rendered as a circle, rectangle and line.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var orange1 = new OrangeDataModel("Orange 1 (Root)");

  var yellow1 = new YellowDataModel("Yellow 1");
  orange1.Children.Add(yellow1);

  var blue1 = new BlueDataModel("Blue 1");
  orange1.Children.Add(blue1);

  var orange2 = new OrangeDataModel("Orange 2");
  var orange3 = new OrangeDataModel("Orange 3");
  blue1.Children.Add(orange2);
  blue1.Children.Add(orange3);

  var yellow2 = new YellowDataModel("Yellow 2");
  blue1.Children.Add(yellow2);

  var blue2 = new BlueDataModel("Blue 2");
  var blue3 = new BlueDataModel("Blue 3");
  yellow2.Children.Add(blue1);
  yellow2.Children.Add(blue3);
      
  var orange4 = new OrangeDataModel("Orange 4");
  yellow1.Children.Add(orange4);

  var root = new ObservableCollection<object> { orange1 };
  this.TreeView.ItemsSource = root;
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<TreeView x:Name="TreeView">
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:OrangeDataModel}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Yellows}">
      <Grid>
        <Ellipse Height="50"
                  Width="50"
                  Fill="DarkOrange" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextValue}" />
      </Grid>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:YellowDataModel}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Blues}">
      <Grid>
        <Rectangle Height="50"
                    Width="50"
                    Fill="Yellow" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextValue}" />
      </Grid>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BlueDataModel}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Oranges}">
      <Grid>
        <Line X2="50"
              Stroke="Blue" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextValue}" />
      </Grid>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

**OrangeDataModel.cs**

```cs
public class OrangeDataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public OrangeDataModel(string textValue)
  {
    this.TextValue = textValue;
    this.Yellows = new ObservableCollection<object>();
  }

  public string TextValue { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<object> Children { get; }
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}
```

**YellowDataModel.cs**

```cs
public class YellowDataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public YellowDataModel(string textValue)
  {
    this.TextValue = textValue;
    this.Blues = new ObservableCollection<object>();
  }

  public string TextValue { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<object> Children{ get; }
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}
```

**BlueDataModel.cs**

```cs
public class BlueDataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public BlueDataModel(string textValue)
  {
    this.TextValue = textValue;
    this.Oranges = new ObservableCollection<object>();
  }

  public string TextValue { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<object> Children{ get; }
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Your answer goes to confirm the knowledge I have. As a matter of fact, I had/have done exactly what you have written here. For some reason unknown to me, I get only the root node when I use the dynamic approach. When I use the static approach, I get the tree as required albeit only to the level that I have defined in the static DataTemplate.
The issue might be in my implementation of the TreeView. I actually have a flat list with child-parent relationships and I lazy-load the items of a node when it is expanded. Using breakpoints, I can see all items currently. I am confused...!

Comment: No problem, we can fix that. First, have you tried the above example to understand how it works? Second, could please provide additional information that shows how you *really* create the tree data structure? In you current code I can't see a flat tree structure. I see a parent-child relationship expressed via collections (aggregation). Lazy loading could also be an issue, but again no information is shared in this regard. For example make sure to always have a single child added so that the node expander is visible.

Comment: Like I have posted a small complete and working example to show how to dynamically populate a TreeView it would be helpful if you could do the same. this allows me (and others) to properly review your code. For example, if it works without lazy-loading then also add your lazy loading logic, please.

Comment: My Bad! My pitfall was that I put the wrong itemssource to the node types. The correct way is this: 

`<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ConfiguratorObjectViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" />`
                
`<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ConfiguratorObjectFamilyViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding ConfiguratorObjects}"/>`

I will be accepting this answer as it explains the right approach and led me to finding a solution to my involuntary itemssource mismatch error! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Have a good time with your project.